# Use HTML input boxes to export the information into an ordered template

Tags: html, templates, input

I have an HTML website that allows people to insert certain information into boxes, like your name and the name of your project.
What i want to achieve is that when the user clicks the submit button all of the information that was inputted will transfer into a template.
Example :
                 
            Config Author Name:

*User enters his name and the webpage types back into a box div this :*

--config.lua--
Author name :

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery.
For each input you have, you can get it value by :

```
$("#input-id").val();
```

So, for example, if you want to place the input values into a template, you do something like this (I suggest you to use a textarea instead of a simple div).

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="#">
    <input id="first-name">
    <input id="last-name">
    <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>
<textarea id="template"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$("#form").on("submit", function() {
    $("#template").val(
        "First name:" + $("#first-name").val() +
        "Last name:" + $("#last-name").val()
    );
});
```

This code will write text your textarea something like that:
First name: John
Last name: Doe

Comment: Still not working, its simply not printing out anything in the text area.

Comment: I just make a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/a8ENh/, and don't forget to include jQuery on your HTML code!

Comment: Would gladly do, but not enough 'reputation' ;(